# Is there a way to identify the date when the "estimated_hours" were added to the issue in Redmine?

Tags: redmine

In the time_entries table it is possible to identify when the "reported_hours" were reported by the user, but is it also possible to identify when the "estimated_hours" were reported?
I would like to be able to see if the users are reporting the reported and estimated hours at the same time.

Comment: Estimated hours can be viewed in journal table...

Comment: I found it, thank you very much!